# What are AnyVal.types useful for?

Tags: scala, types

I've accidentally written this line of code:

```
scala> val f = Int
f: Int.type = object scala.Int
```

Seems to work for every subtype of `AnyVal` except for `AnyVal` itself.

Is there anything I can use `f` for or is it just an implementation detail of Scala leaking out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Int` companion object is [documented here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int%24). It doesn't provide a lot, but here are a couple things:

```
scala> val f = Int
f: Int.type = object scala.Int

scala> f.MaxValue
res1: Int = 2147483647

scala> f.box(2)
res2: java.lang.Integer = 2
```

Comment: Oh silly me, it's the companion object...I guess it's time to go to bed now ;)

Comment: Perhaps most importantly, the `AnyVal` companion objects are used as parameters to the `@specialized` annotation.